# Recording from microphone and replaying sound with a delay in Chuck

Tags: chuck

I'm trying to replay sound currently recorded on mic with an adjustable delay.
This should help to improve pronaunciation ability. I found the example, which seems to do what I want:

```
adc => DelayL delay => dac;
.05::second => delay.max => delay.delay;
while( true ) 5::second => now;
```

Unfortunatelly, the delay is not exact the time I define. The replay starts about 0,25 sec later and not 50ms as I want.
Is there a way to set smaller delay?

Comment: Could it be that the extra delay you hear is just the latency of your connected microphone? (which is common for a connected Audio device via USB for example)

Comment: I think no. If I switch mic directly to speakers adc = > dac - there is no delay.

Comment: I don't know if it makes a difference if you try to use a non-interpolating digital delay-line (using the Delay class) or a fractional-length digital delay-line using a first-order allpass filter (using the DelayA class) instead of the DelayL class.
I am to less an expert in this. 
If it is not enough to simply adapt the duration for your needs (just using smaller values until it sounds like you want) - you can try to ask on the [chuck-users mailing list](https://lists.cs.princeton.edu/mailman/listinfo/chuck-users).